# bootstrap, javascript, jquery and ajax what are those?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to start to learn the client side scripting to make a web page more dynamic while collecting some information about, came to know some programming languages like javascript, ajax are out there and I figured that jquery is javascript library(may be I'm wrong) but still I'm not sure (concepts are not cleared) that what actually are those. There are a lot of question to ask like :

1. What is javascript and what can i do with it ?
2. Details about jquery and do I need to know javascript for working with jquery ?
3. What is angularjs and what can i do with it ?
4. What is ajax and what can i do with it ?
5. what is bootstrap and what can i do with it ?

I basically work with PHP i.e. server side scripting and know a little bit of HTML and CSS.

6. Do I need to be an expert in HTML and CSS to work with the language mentioned above ?

Finally it will be helpful if a starting point to learn the client side scripting is suggested I mean from where I can start ?? A little bit of a guide line will be much appreciated. Too much confusion !!

Comment: this is what google is for, not what stackoverflow is for

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info  |  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info  |  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ajax/info   |   http://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/info   |   http://stackoverflow.com/tags/twitter-bootstrap/info

Answer (score 2):

The most common use of JavaScript is to add client-side behavior to HTML pages, a.k.a. Dynamic HTML (DHTML). Scripts are embedded in or included from HTML pages and interact with the Document Object Model (DOM) of the page.

As quoted on official jQuery website, "it is a fast and concise JavaScript Library that simplifies HTML document traversing, event handling, animating, and Ajax interactions for rapid web development." In order to work with jQuery, you should be aware of the basics of JavaScript, HTML and CSS.

AJAX allows web pages to be updated asynchronously by exchanging small amounts of data with the server behind the scenes. This means that it is possible to update parts of a web page, without reloading the whole page.

Bootstra[ is an html, css, javascript framework that you can use as basis for creating web sites or web applications. It is a combination of HTML, CSS, and Javascript code designed to help build user interface components.

I have no experience with angularjs, but you might wanna look it up: That is also what I did to find the definitions above. I would recommend to learn CSS and HTML before using any other language / library, because they are all build around HTML / CSS.

If you have no experience with either HTML/CSS or client-side languages, I would suggest you take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/, a website that explains all the important and most used parts of the languages listed above.

Answer (score 2):

1. JavaScript is client-side (in most cases) programming language that allows you to do things like operations on HTML, page elements, navigating, and many more
2. JQuery very simplifies working with HTML (operations on DOM structure). It has distinct syntax, you can start from learning it before JavaScript
3. Angular is JavaScript framework for creating SPA pages, if you are beginner, you'd better start with JQuery
4. AJAX technology allows you to make async requests to server (without reloading web page) ([jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))
5. Bootstrap is popular template which allows to make web sites quickly without much knowledge of CSS and JavaScript. It has many nice things bundled with it, so you can start using it as boilerplate. It uses jQuery too

And google google google :)

Answer (score 2):

welcome to the next step in programming. For client side in my eyes the big language you should start with is JavaScript. This leads me to the answers for some of your questions:

1. With JS you can do a lot on the client side. It is basically a really simple Java oriented script language. It can handle a lot of the user interacting based stuff and quite funny but simple animations, (e.g. a simple countdown or animated letters). But it is limitated by its simplicity. You can (but don't do anymore) write really complex code there, but it will be quite hard to understand it in some future time.
2. JQuery is basically a powerful extension to JS but mostly fit to DOM-parsing and really cool and complex animation. It runs with JS and the JQuery Core. It is not necessary to know any JS for using JQuery, but it would be helpful for sure.
3. Withd AJAX you can do asynchronous JS and XML requests. When you look to html, you will see it is made for synchronous requests. Whenever you want to have something from the server, you need to reload a complete page and not only the specific part you wanted to have updated. AJAX helps you out with this. The best example here is the typical auto fill search form. While you type a word it shows already some suggestions what it could be.
4. You should have understood html and css for working with JS and JQuery, because you often take some html-tags, get its values or properties, modify it with JS/Jquery and write it back (DOM-manipulation for example) or you take a html-tag and use some JQuery animation and need to declare css-properties with it.

3 & 5. I have never used by now^^

I have started to use JQuery 3 years ago and just took a problem, tried to look in the documentation for it and then I solved it. jquery.com is a good help here

Greetz

Answer (score 1):

**In answer to your questions:**

**1:What is javascript and what can i do with it ?**

A: An object-oriented computer programming language commonly used to create interactive effects within web browsers.

**2: Details about jquery and do I need to know javascript for working with jquery ?**

A: jQuery is a fast, small, and feature-rich JavaScript library. It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers. And no you do now necessarily need to be a master Javascript coder but it is a library of Javascript codes and uses similar  syntax so an understand would help you understand and debug. I would learn Javascript first.

**3: What is angularjs and what can i do with it ?**

A: AngularJS is a structural framework for dynamic web apps. It lets you use HTML as your template language and lets you extend HTML's syntax to express your application's components clearly and succinctly. Angular's data binding and dependency injection eliminate much of the code you would otherwise have to write.

**4: What is ajax and what can i do with it ?**

A: Ajax (also AJAX; /ˈeɪdʒæks/; short for asynchronous JavaScript + XML) is a group of interrelated Web development techniques used on the client-side to create asynchronous Web applications.

**5: what is bootstrap and what can i do with it ?**

- Bootstrap is a free collection of tools for creating websites and web
- applications Bootstrap contains HTML and CSS-based design templates for text, forms, buttons, navigation and other components
- Bootstrap also contains optional JavaScript extensions
- Bootstrap is open source and available on GitHub

**6: Do I need to be an expert in HTML and CSS to work with the language mentioned above ?**

A: I would suggest not focusing on being a master but taking time with the above one step at a time, get a handle on basic syntax like HTML and CSS and then throw in some function when you are ready with Javascript. Please do not rush the process and enjoy it. Those tools above can take people years to master and they have taken years to develop and are still growing so please have respect for that also.

Answer (score 0):

javascript is client side scripting language...
jquery/angularjs/bootstrap are all the frameworks built using javascript that helps you build dynamic websites....

You need to have basic understanding of HTML and CSS to interpret javascript better. 
www.w3schools.com is the best place to being with. It has tutorials to almost all the list you've mentioned above.